# Setup SSL and Access https on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https, postman

Based on [the Tomcat document](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html), I run the following command to generate a SSL key store.

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

And I get the followings:

```
Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\Users\me\.keystore -destkeystore C:\Users\me\.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12".
```

So, I run the above command.

Next, I configure the server.xml as

```
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"  
           keystoreFile="C:\Users\me\.keystore"
            keystorePass="password"/>
```

For a Rest API of an applicatiion deployed on the TC, I still can have an access on 8080 port with http. But for the 8443 port, I get "Could not get any response" for https on Postman. Based on Postman's instruction,

```
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked: Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
```

I make the change and I still get the  "Could not get any response".

To my understanding, a client needs the public key stored in the keystore for decrytion. How a client gets the key? Do I have to have a Certificate? The web application is not public facing, but it is used internally.

The following are output of "netstat -a"

```
c:\>netstat -a

Active Connections

Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    0.0.0.0:135            me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:445            me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:2179           me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:4000           me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:5040           me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:5473           me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:7680           me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:8009           me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:49664          me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:49665          me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:49666          me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:49667          me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:49668          me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:49669          me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:49670          me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:63938          me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:63939          me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:64466          me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:1023         me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:4000         me-171106:49984      TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:4000         me-171106:50004      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:4000         me-171106:50019      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:6942         me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:8005         me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:14617        me-171106:50041      FIN_WAIT_2
TCP    127.0.0.1:19361        me-171106:50006      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:19385        me-171106:50020      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:49985        me-171106:33544      TIME_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:50004        me-171106:4000       ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:50006        me-171106:19361      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:50019        me-171106:4000       ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:50020        me-171106:19385      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:50041        me-171106:14617      CLOSE_WAIT
TCP    127.0.0.1:57130        me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:57130        me-171106:61593      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:57738        me-171106:62522      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:60959        me-171106:60960      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:60960        me-171106:60959      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:61582        me-171106:61583      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:61583        me-171106:61582      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:61593        me-171106:57130      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:61594        me-171106:61595      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:61595        me-171106:61594      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:62522        me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:62522        me-171106:57738      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:62743        me-171106:62744      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:62744        me-171106:62743      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:62745        me-171106:62746      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:62746        me-171106:62745      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:62752        me-171106:62753      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:62753        me-171106:62752      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:62754        me-171106:62755      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:62755        me-171106:62754      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:62756        me-171106:62757      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:62757        me-171106:62756      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:62758        me-171106:62759      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:62759        me-171106:62758      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:63342        me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:64418        me-171106:64419      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:64419        me-171106:64418      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:64593        me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    172.25.25.141:139      me-171106:0          LISTENING
TCP    172.25.25.141:49623    40.97.48.98:https      ESTABLISHED
TCP    172.25.25.141:49797    40.97.48.98:https      ESTABLISHED
TCP    172.25.25.141:49898    151.101.65.69:https    TIME_WAIT
TCP    172.25.25.141:49911    stackoverflow:https    ESTABLISHED
TCP    172.25.25.141:49981    40.97.48.98:https      ESTABLISHED
TCP    172.25.25.141:50014    server-52-84-16-177:https  ESTABLISHED
TCP    172.25.25.141:50015    ec2-52-71-1-248:https  ESTABLISHED
TCP    172.25.25.141:50028    ec2-50-16-236-165:http  ESTABLISHED
TCP    172.25.25.141:50029    sea15s07-in-f4:https   CLOSE_WAIT
TCP    172.25.25.141:50030    gigaspeedtest:http     ESTABLISHED
TCP    172.25.25.141:50031    sea15s07-in-f78:https  ESTABLISHED
TCP    172.25.25.141:50032    vip1:http              ESTABLISHED
TCP    172.25.25.141:50033    vip1:http              ESTABLISHED
TCP    172.25.25.141:50034    vip1:http              ESTABLISHED
TCP    172.25.25.141:50035    vip1:http              ESTABLISHED
TCP    172.25.25.141:50036    vip1:http              ESTABLISHED
TCP    172.25.25.141:50037    vip1:http              ESTABLISHED
TCP    172.25.25.141:50038    sea15s07-in-f78:https  ESTABLISHED
```

The port 8443 is not on the list. Also, after TC starting up, the following messages are shown in the console

```
Dec 19, 2017 1:32:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Dec 19, 2017 1:32:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Dec 19, 2017 1:32:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 18955 ms
```

The port 8443 isn't mentioned.

Comment: Yes, SSL/TLS passes the server public key to the client in a certificate, see any tutorial or our in-house epic https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work/ ; `keytool -genkeypair` creates (also) a selfsigned certificate, see the documentation. A selfsigned cert is sufficient for testing and debugging, and _may_ be sufficient for internal use, but that's a different Q and probably belongs on security.SX instead. Standard drill for connectivity problem: what does `netstat` (or `ss`) show? What result from `telnet netcat socat` or similar? Anything in the logs?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks very much for your inputs. I add an output of netstat in my question. I don't have telnet, net, nor socat in my Windows box yet. The port isn't shown in the netstat. Somethig isn't right. There isn't any log related with the request. I guess the service isn't hit.

Comment: Yes if 8443 isn't in netstat and there isn't even an attempt at a handler for it in the startup log, it's not there. Maybe you left the `<Connector ... />` element commented out?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved. The cause was due to TC configuration. It was messed up somehow and the port 8443. Now, I can access those REST end-points on port 8443 when SSL certificate verification is off with Postman.